# Is there an Integration knowledge module for oracle to external table

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-data-integrator

I'd like to export my tables without having to load it into memory on the agent. Is there any knowledge module which would let me export an oracle table to an external table (csv) in ODI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default IKM for that but you may look at the Oracle to Oracle Datapump LKM for reference